# Remote sed to change file is failing

Tags: sed

I have the following script that defines an OLD and a NEW string. I want to replace the OLD with the NEW using sed over a remote connection. All the commands besides the sed appear to be working. I have tried adjusting punctuation and using pipes instead of forward slashes with sed to no avail.
Doing the sed command from a command prompt works, but within the script, it does not.
I would appreciate any input on this.

```
#!/bin/ksh

OLD="command\[Check_Memory_OS_10038\]=/opt/tools/nagitem/libexec/check_mem.pl -w 80,10 -c 90,25";export OLD
NEW="command\[Check_Memory_OS_10038\]=/opt/tools/nagitem/libexec/check_mem_ng.sh -w 80 -c 90";export NEW
DEST1="/opt/tools/nagitem/libexec/"
DEST2="/opt/tools/nagitem/nrdp/clients/nrds/"

for x in `cat /home/joe/nagios/hostlist`
do
SSH_STATUS=$(ssh -n -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$x "pwd" >/dev/null)
  if [[ $? = "0" ]];then
    scp -p /home/joe/nagios/check_mem_ng.sh $x:/tmp
    ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $x "sudo /usr/localcw/bin/eksh -c '/bin/cp /tmp/check_mem_ng.sh $DEST1;chown nagitem:nagitem $DEST1/check_mem_ng.sh;cd $DEST2; /bin/sed -i -e 's/'$OLD'/'$NEW'/g' /opt/tools/nagitem/nrdp/clients/nrds/nrds.cfg '"
else
   echo "Cannot connect to $x" >> badhosts
fi
done
```

Error received is:
/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 39: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Note how your strings contain `/`, which is the default delimiter in the `s///` command. Either escape them in your strings, or use another delimiter character (`s@@@`?).

Comment: I tried the following to use pipes in the sed, ending up with more errors.

```ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $x "sudo /usr/localcw/bin/eksh -c '/bin/cp /tmp/check_mem_ng.sh $DEST1;chown nagitem:nagitem $DEST1/check_mem_ng.sh;cd $DEST
2; /bin/sed -i -e 's|'$OLD'|'$NEW'|g' /opt/tools/nagitem/nrdp/clients/nrds/nrds.cfg '"```

Comment: When I try to escape my strings, I get this error:

/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code of yours required an overhaul in a couple of places.

- The initializations of environment vars `$OLD` n `$NEW` to use no escaping as they get backslash ed downstream, lest they be double escaped.
- Escape $OLD var so that it becomes saf e for plug in on the LHS of a sed substitute command.
- Similarly, Escape the $NEW var for use on RHS of the substitute command.
- The sed command is using single quotes within single quotes under the overall umbrella of double quotes , so they were escaped taking care to escape any single quotes within new or old var values too.

```
#!/bin/ksh

OLD="command[Check_Memory_OS_10038]=/opt/tools/nagitem/libexec/check_mem.pl -w 80,10 -c 90,25";export OLD
NEW="command[Check_Memory_OS_10038]=/opt/tools/nagitem/libexec/check_mem_ng.sh -w 80 -c 90";export NEW
DEST1="/opt/tools/nagitem/libexec/"
DEST2="/opt/tools/nagitem/nrdp/clients/nrds/"

#--------------------
# escape variables
eOLD=$(printf '%s\n' "$OLD" | sed -e 's:[][\/^$.*]:\\&:g' -e "s:':&\\&&:g")
eNEW=$(printf '%s\n' "$NEW" | sed -e 's:[\/&]:\\&:g' -e "s:':&\\&&:g")
#--------------------

for x in `cat /home/joe/nagios/hostlist`
do
SSH_STATUS=$(ssh -n -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $USER@$x "pwd" >/dev/null)
  if [[ $? = "0" ]];then
    scp -p /home/joe/nagios/check_mem_ng.sh $x:/tmp
    ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" $x "sudo /usr/localcw/bin/eksh -c '/bin/cp /tmp/check_mem_ng.sh $DEST1;chown nagitem:nagitem $DEST1/check_mem_ng.sh;cd $DEST2; /bin/sed -i -e '\\''s/$eOLD/$eNEW/g'\\'' /opt/tools/nagitem/nrdp/clients/nrds/nrds.cfg'"
else
   echo "Cannot connect to $x" >> badhosts
fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the rewrite, but I get the following errors.
When the script first executes:
```sed: -e expression #1, char 17: unterminated `s' command```

After the script has fully executed and has exited, the following error appears:
```/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression```

Comment: Rather than trying to do everything on the remote host, just `cat` the remote file and work on it locally (or `scp` it over here). Then transfer it back. This makes quoting easier.

Comment: @jackcsprat can you place an `echo` before thev`ssh` command and share the output. Also copy paste from my code only as I made extensive rewrite.

Comment: @guest_7

At exit of script:
```check_mem_ng.sh                                                                                           100% 6294     6.2KB/s   00:00
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking no myserver sudo /usr/localcw/bin/eksh -c '/bin/cp /tmp/check_mem_ng.sh /opt/tools/nagitem/libexec/;chown nagitem:nagitem /opt/tools/nagitem/libexec//check_mem_ng.sh;cd /opt/tools/nagitem/nrdp/clients/nrds/; /bin/sed -i -e '\''s//command[[]Check_Memory_OS_10038[]]=\/opt\/tools\/nagitem\/libexec\/check_mem_ng.sh -w 80 -c 90/g'\'' /opt/tools/nagitem/nrdp/clients/nrds/nrds.cfg ' ```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the data. It enabled me to get to the issue. Now  copy again and give it a spin. It will fly now.

Answer (score 0):

You quote your eksh parameter with single quotes `'`. Inside single quotes, there is no possibility to expand special characters. So your `$DEST` and other variables are not expanded, leaving some weird residuals.

Comment: Note that the `eksh -c` invocation itself is within double quotes. The shell would therefore expand the variables.